# Regex - Exclude '1' or '11' from middle of capture

Tags: regex

I have this expression for capturing text of seasons and their years

`(?:WIN\w+|SPR\w+|SUM\w+|FA\w+) \d{4}`

The typical match I want to capture is formatted as 'FALL 2011' or 'SPRING 2019' etc, but Summer deviates from this format and can be either 'Summer 1 2011' or 'Summer 11 2011' which is being captured like 'Summer 1201' or 'Summer 1120'.  I want the expression to match on the seasons still and capture the year, but for Summer it needs to ignore a '1' or '11' before capturing the year.

I was trying to modify it by adding a negative lookahead to ignore any pattern of '1(space)' or '11(space)' it finds before the year, since in most cases it will just find the year which consists of four consecutive numbers, and in the case of Summer it should find and skip the 1 or 11, but my testing has shown my modified expression doesn't work.  I'm still pretty inexperienced with regex.

Comment: Try `\b(?:((?:WIN|SPR|FA)[a-zA-Z]+)|(SUM[a-zA-Z]+)(?: \d{1,2})?) (\d{4})\b`, see https://regex101.com/r/aRbHgS/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "anchor" to four last digits after season. Below is pattern to do that:

```
(SUMMER|FALL|WINTER|SPRING).+?(\d{4})(?=\D|$)
```

Explanation:

`(SUMMER|FALL|WINTER|SPRING)` - alternation, match one of the four seasons and store it in first capturing group

`.+?` - match 1+ of any characters, non greedy

`(\d{4})` - match four digits and store it in second capturing group

`(?=\D|$)` - positive lookahead, assert what follows is non digit `\D` or end of string `$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V6L5DY/1)

Comment: Needs to be `/.../i` insensitive in order to match "Summer"

Comment: I think SUMMER is okay, I checked my data and my original post was incorrectly using 'Summer', 'SUMMER' is what we will see.   Thank you Michal, that solution worked like a charm.

Comment: Note that this matches `SUMMER 20 2020` and `FALL 1 2020`. If one has confidence in the data that's OK (those strings won't be present) but if one purpose of the regex is to perform a limited check on the data those strings should not match. The question does tell whether the regex should do this partial check on the data.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't given the language you are using. If it supports `\K`, as does `PCRE (PHP)` and others, you can split your string on the match of the following regular expression.

```
^(?:(?:FALL|WINTER|SPRING)\K +|SUMMER\K(?: +11?)? +)(?=\d{4}$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zz8Ju3/3/)

If the string were one of the following

```
SUMMER 11 2011
      ^^^^
SUMMER 1 2011
      ^^^
SUMMER 2011
      ^
FALL 2011
    ^
```

the regex would match the character(s) perched on hat(s). If the string were first of these examples, splitting on `" 11 "` would produce the array `["SUMMER", "2011"]`.

If the string were either of the following:

```
SUMMER 12 2011
WINTER 1 2020
```

there would be no match, signalling a problem with the data.

The PCRE regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^
(?:
  (?:FALL|WINTER|SPRING)  match 'FALL', 'WINTER' or 'SPRING' 
  \K +                    forget everything matched so far then match 1+ spaces
  |                       or
  SUMMER                  match 'SUMMER'
  \K                      forget everything matched so far
  (?: +11?)? +            optionally match 1+ spaces, then '1', then optionally
                          match '1', followed by 1+ spaces
)                         end non-capture group
(?=\d{4}$)                match 4 digits at end of the line in a positive lookahead
```

Taken from the demo link, "\K resets the starting point of the reported match."